# Check if bash variable equals 0

Tags: bash, equals, zero

I have a bash variable depth and I would like to test if it equals 0. In case yes, I want to stop executing of script. So far I have:

```
zero=0;

if [ $depth -eq $zero ]; then
    echo "false";
    exit;
fi
```

Unfortunately, this leads to:

```
 [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

(might be a bit inaccurate due to translation)

Please, how can I modify my script to get it working?

Answer (score 267):

Looks like your `depth` variable is unset. This means that the expression `[ $depth -eq $zero ]` becomes `[ -eq 0 ]` after bash substitutes the values of the variables into the expression. The problem here is that the `-eq` operator is incorrectly used as an operator with only one argument (the zero), but it requires two arguments. That is why you get the *unary operator* error message.

**EDIT:** As **Doktor J** mentioned in his comment to this answer, a safe way to avoid problems with unset variables in checks is to enclose the variables in `""`. See his comment for the explanation.

```
if [ "$depth" -eq "0" ]; then
   echo "false";
   exit;
fi
```

An unset variable used with the  `[` command appears empty to bash. You can verify this using the below tests which all evaluate to `true` because `xyz` is either empty or unset:

- `if [ -z ] ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`
- `xyz=""; if [ -z "$xyz" ] ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`
- `unset xyz; if [ -z "$xyz" ] ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`

Comment: I am getting depth as a result from another program. I tried to echo it and there was nothing in the output. However, when I use [[]] as @Jacek Dominiak suggested, script works correctly (what is quite strange if variable is really unset). I have to admit that I do not really understand whats going on here...

Comment: Your depth variable is unset. That means bash sees an expression which says `[ -eq 0 ]; then` which doesn't make sense to it. `[[ ]]` is the safer version which seems to make bash see it as [[ null -eq 0 ]] which is correct.

Comment: A safer way to check is to enclose both sides in double quotes, i.e. `if [ "$depth" -eq "0" ]`; this way, an unset variable (`$depth`) evaluates to "" (which of course does not equal zero)

Comment: @DoktorJ Agreed, that's a better way to do it. I'll update the code.

Comment: "An unset variable used with the  [ command appears empty to bash." that helped me! Thanks

Comment: This gives me: `[: Illegal number:` error.

Comment: This does not work if the output is a decimal : `[: : integer expression expected`

Answer (score 87):

Double parenthesis `(( ... ))` is used for arithmetic operations.

Double square brackets `[[ ... ]]` can be used to compare and examine numbers (only integers are supported), with the following operators:

```
· NUM1 -eq NUM2 returns true if NUM1 and NUM2 are numerically equal.

· NUM1 -ne NUM2 returns true if NUM1 and NUM2 are not numerically equal.

· NUM1 -gt NUM2 returns true if NUM1 is greater than NUM2.

· NUM1 -ge NUM2 returns true if NUM1 is greater than or equal to NUM2.

· NUM1 -lt NUM2 returns true if NUM1 is less than NUM2.

· NUM1 -le NUM2 returns true if NUM1 is less than or equal to NUM2.
```

For example

```
if [[ $age > 21 ]] # bad, > is a string comparison operator

if [ $age > 21 ] # bad, > is a redirection operator

if [[ $age -gt 21 ]] # okay, but fails if $age is not numeric

if (( $age > 21 )) # best, $ on age is optional
```

Comment: Can you provide some reasoning/evidence why some approaches are good and others bad?

Comment: @Dennis: [This](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) seems to verify the statements in the answer (-> the different brackets for string vs. integer comparison)

Comment: `best, $ on age is optional` It's not working without `$`

Comment: `if (( age > 21 ))` and `if (( $age > 21 ))` is different sometimes. You can see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2004

Answer (score 27):

Try:

```
zero=0;

if [[ $depth -eq $zero ]]; then
  echo "false";
  exit;
fi
```

Comment: The double brackets are smarter about preserving unset/null variables as a separate word in the expression.

Comment: @pavel, [ is a bash built-in, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Answer (score 27):

you can also use this format and use comparison operators like '==' '<='

```
  if (( $total == 0 )); then
      echo "No results for ${1}"
      return
  fi
```

Answer (score 9):

Specifically: `((depth))`. By example, the following prints `1`.

```
declare -i x=0
((x)) && echo $x

x=1
((x)) && echo $x
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
: ${depth?"Error Message"} ## when your depth variable is not even declared or is unset.
```

NOTE: Here it's just `?` after `depth`.

or

```
: ${depth:?"Error Message"} ## when your depth variable is declared but is null like: "depth=".
```

NOTE: Here it's `:?` after `depth`.

Here if the variable `depth` is found `null` it will print the error message and then exit.