# Compaing integers in bash

Tags: bash, numbers

I have been using integer comparisons with standard approach

```
(( n == 0 ))
```

But this time I want to check if the variable is not zero.  But I have found that `!=` is only for strings.  Is this correct?  How is this integer comparison customarily approached?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if bash variable equals 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086109/check-if-bash-variable-equals-0)

Comment: It's not correct. See the bash man-page, section ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in my bash:

```
if (( 1 != 2 )); then echo Y; fi
Y
```

Comment: What about 0 != 00? That would distinguish string comparisons from numeric comparisons.

Comment: It works properly.

Comment: Are we settled on using `!=` with `(())`?  Have bash superceded the previous insistence by some that `!=` is for strings.

Comment: @Phil: As far as I can see in my test, != works with integers in (( )). Usually I use [[ ]] when comparing strings and != works there too as expected.

Comment: @rghome : 0 and 00 are numerically equal. Therefore `(( 0 != 00)) || echo false` outputs _false_.

Comment: @Phil : You do not have **any** string comparision in arithmetic context.